SSRS report parameter control image issue
Some special symbols are displayed instead of Date Control, Drop down symbol in ssrs report server. For example H is displayed instead of Date Control to pick the date. K instead of dropdown symbol. Below screenshot give more details of the issue.

I have observed that, if the parameter panel loading is taking more time then these special symbols are displayed otherwise it displays dropdown or date controls properly.
Could you please help me on this issue

I have also experienced the parameters' panel rendering in an unexpected way when using a large or slow report. I'm only able to resolve the issue by improving the report's performance or by checking if the server is under a heavy load.
To improve report performance you can review your parameter queries, if you are using any. You are only having issues loading the parameters panel, not running the report. You should check to see if there is a particular query that is running slow or if they are pulling any unnecessary fields. Typically, you want the parameter queries to run in less than a few seconds and to only return a value and label field for you drop down.
You should also consider reviewing you report server resources. Your report may be perfectly fine, but if someone else is running a large report or if your server is shared by other applications then that may be affecting your report performance.
Here is a good resource for looking more at how to improve SSRS performance. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3659/sql-server-reporting-services-best-practices-for-performance-and-maintenance/
